# What is the best way to integrate jbpm 6 with spring?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jbpm

I am trying to integrate jbpm6 with my web application. I am able to understand how to execute a simple process jbpm6. Please let me know where i can understand the simple way to integrate jbpm6 with a spring mvc hibernate application.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen http://mswiderski.blogspot.be/2014/01/jbpm-6-with-spring.html ?  There's also some info in the documentation.